# Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a class to store data and then using controller and a view to show the data on the screen on a Website using MVC3 however I am coming across an error, help would be appreciated.

Class:

```
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TicketBookingEntities>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TicketBookingEntities context)
        {
            var productions = new List<Production>
            {
                new Production { Name = "Peter Pan" },
                new Production { Name = "Mary Poppins" },
                new Production { Name = "Pirates of the Carribean" },
                new Production { Name = "Joseph" },
                new Production { Name = "Billy Elliot" },

            };

            var directors = new List<Director>
            {
                new Director { Name = "Jason Brown" },
                new Director { Name = "Dan Elish" },
                new Director { Name = "Lee Hall" },
                new Director { Name = "Billie Armstrong" },
                new Director { Name = "Willy Russell" },

            };

            new List<Performance>
            {


                new Performance {Title = "Test", Genre = productions.Single(g => g.Name == "Peter Pan"), Director = directors.Single(a => a.Name == "Jason Brown"), Price = 9.99M, AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },


            }.ForEach(a => context.Performances.Add(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
        {
            var productionModel = storeDB.Productions.Include("Performances")
                .Single(g => g.Name == genre);

            return View(productionModel);

        }
```

View:

```
@model Assignment2.Models.Production

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browsing Production: @Model.Name</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var performance in Model.Performances)
    {
        <li>
            @performance.Title

        </li>
    }

</ul>
```

The Error:

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

Comment: before your `foreach` add something like `@if(Model.Performances)` to check whether the collection is `null`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a list, you only have one element. Take out the foreach loop.

Comment: I did originally have a list but I took some of the list out due to the error occurring and just left one item in to test it

Comment: @user1300580 - Try making a more verbose view model, entity models do not work well as view models.

Comment: Managed to solve the issue, changed genre to production on the controller

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the issue, changed genre to production on the controller